# Rename [ac*] tags to [assassins-creed*]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Since the character limit for tags was increased to 35 a few months ago, there are a few Assassin’s Creed tags which haven’t been renamed yet.

- [ac-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-brotherhood) -> [assassins-creed-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-brotherhood)
- [ac-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-revelations) -> [assassins-creed-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revelations)
- [ac-syndicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-syndicate) -> [assassins-creed-syndicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-syndicate)
- [ac3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac3-liberation) -> [assassins-creed-3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3-liberation)
- [ac4-kenways-fleet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac4-kenways-fleet) -> [assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet)
- [assassins-creed-fc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-fc) -> [assassins-creed-freedom-cry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-freedom-cry)
- [assassins-creed-pl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-pl) -> [assassins-creed-project-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-project-legacy)

Would anyone be against renaming these tags?

Comment: Fully support this with the additional characters being added to tags.

Comment: You can add `ac-revelations` and `ac-syndicate` to the listings

Comment: @Wondercricket Good catch. Added

Comment: Will any of the Assassin's Creed games not fit in the character limit? It may be undesirable to have a few tags that don't match.

Comment: @RobRose All the tags are well under 35 characters. These tags were originally abbreviated to fit the old 25 character limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are all now done.

- [ac-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-brotherhood) -> [assassins-creed-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-brotherhood)
- [ac-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-revelations) -> [assassins-creed-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revelations)
- [ac-syndicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-syndicate) -> [assassins-creed-syndicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-syndicate)
- [ac3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac3-liberation) -> [assassins-creed-3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3-liberation)
- [ac4-kenways-fleet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac4-kenways-fleet) -> [assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet)
- [assassins-creed-fc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-fc) -> [assassins-creed-freedom-cry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-freedom-cry)
- [assassins-creed-pl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-pl) -> [assassins-creed-project-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-project-legacy)

Comment: It appears that none of the tag wikis or excerpts were transferred over.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - Most seem to have come over - the only one that seemed to be missing was syndicate. I've rescued that one, the ones with fewer questions don't appear to have had any to begin with.